# Unable to login to mysql from php

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 on a virtual machine ( i had problems with newer versions and Ldap) for testing. 
I set up two way ssl authentication for my test website,  mysql and phpmyadmin. So far so good. 
I am able to loggin to phpmyadmin (i made a user and i can also login) by typing https://localhost/phpmyadmin but whenever i try to connect from a php to the database i get an access denied error for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (also tried with root) (using password yes).

Password and the php file i use to connect is not the problem. I tried them in Xampp on windows and i can connect. What am i doing wrong.

All the fixes i have seen so far are for when you are unable to login to phpmyadmin. But i can login. It's just when i try to use mysqli to connect from php it doesn't

Comment: root pass empty tried?

Comment: Probably sharing some code with the connection to the database would be helpful to understand your problem.

Comment: Please, always show us ALL the error message, not a summary of it

Comment: Is the PHP Code running Inside the VM or outside?

Comment: @AlessandroMandelli What code sample ?

Answer (score -2):

Please share the code your using to connect to the database, from that we would be able to advise.

Comment: Please dont make comments in an Answer.

Comment: Also someone has already asked the OP to show us the code, correctly in a comment, so this is also unnecessary